# How to solve mysql (errno: 135 "No more room in record file") — Please check privileges of directory containing database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, xampp

I cannot create the following table:

```
create table measurement(
    user_id int(7),
    age int(3),
    gender varchar(8),
    height int(5),
    weight int(5),
    bmi int(5),
    body_fat int(5),
    lean_mass int(5),
    measurement_date date,
    PRIMARY key (user_id),
    FOREIGN key(user_id) REFERENCES user_info(user_id)
    );
```

Whenver I perform the above query it shows:

> Can't create table `measurement` (errno: 135 "No more room in record file") — 
>   Please check privileges of directory containing database.

But I can create the above table if it has only 2 columns like:

```
create table measurement( user_id int(7), age int(3));
```

If I try to alter table to add more columns it gives error.
How do i solve this error: errno: 135 "No more room in record file") — Please check privileges of directory containing database.

Comment: Read carefully: [How to Repair MyISAM Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/myisam-repair.html). *Note that error 135 (no more room in record file) and error 136 (no more room in index file) are not errors that can be fixed by a simple repair. In this case, you must use ALTER TABLE to increase the MAX_ROWS and AVG_ROW_LENGTH table option values*

Answer (score 0):

Update: The drive I installed xampp had less than 10mb free space. I uninstalled it and installed again to a bigger directory and it works just fine now